# meaning of (verb stem)＋ませぬな

Tags: conjugations

I'm reading a manga, and in it one of the characters uses grammar that I've never seen before. The sentence is as follows:

> 小姓さんが見当たりませぬな。是非お会いしたかったのですが。

I understand pretty much everything else in the sentence:

[小姓]{こしょう}さん = page

見当たる = find

是非 = certainly

お会いしたかった = (humbly) wanted to meet

But because of this conjugation that I'm not familiar with, I'm not sure how it all fits together. What does +ませぬな mean?

Comment: 小姓 is not a name. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/78952/m0u/

Comment: Are you sure you have never seen anything very close to ませぬ?  And the な is a particle, not a part of the verb conjugation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [ぬ indicates the negative](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/235/difference-between-negative-forms-%E3%81%9A-and-%E3%81%AC) (as in Classical Japanese) and ~ませぬ is in fact the precursor of the modern ~ません.
- な is a variant of ね

  <sub>(see also [What nuance does "ですな" bring?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6806/what-nuance-brings-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%AA) and [「ね」 vs 「な」 in 「そうだね」 /「そうね」/ 「そうですね」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13474/%E3%81%AD-vs-%E3%81%AA-in-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0%E3%81%AD-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%AD-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%AD))</sub>

Since Manga often indicate the end of a sentence by a line (or column) break, rather than a period, I would bet that the sentence is

> 小姓さんが見当たりませぬな
>   是非お会いしたかったのですが。

In any case,

> 小姓さんが見当たりませぬな = 小姓さんが見当たりませんね (*modulo nuances*)

Comment: Ah, makes sense since this manga takes place in 19th century Japan. Thanks!