# しな at the end of a sentence

Tags: words, meaning

In the manga Yotsubato, the main character Yotsuba's father says 「ジャンボが二人分働くしな」.  I understand the sentence as a whole, I think, but I don't understand the しな at the end.

Here's the full dialogue:

> よつば：ジャンボ、しばらく見ないうちにまた大きくなった！
>   ジャンボ：お？どこでおぼえたそのセリフ
>   お父さん：まあいいか。ジャンボが二人分働くしな

Comment: Do you think you could ask your ～てくれ question separately?  We'd like to keep things to one question per question here on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'll just remove it as it's already been answered.

Comment: Who or what is よつば?  Are they really relevant to the question?  Please edit the title to indicate what you're actually asking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 〜し〜し is a common pattern for listing things. Although the pattern strictly speaking requires at least two list items, in colloquial speech it often occurs by itself. Here, the previous discussion probably contains some things which are good about ジャンボ and the fact that he works for two is just another good thing about him.
  <sub>Related questions: (1) [Are there various ways to use ~し?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/are-there-various-ways-to-use-%E3%81%97), (2) [Joining adjectives with し before a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/joining-adjectives-with-%E3%81%97-before-a-noun), (3) [The many ways to say "and" in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/474/the-many-ways-to-say-and-in-japanese?lq=1), (4) [What is the し particle and how do you use it?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13397/what-is-the-%E3%81%97-particle-and-how-do-you-use-it)</sub>
- な is a variant of ね.
  <sub>Related questions: (1) [What nuance does "ですな" bring?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6806/what-nuance-brings-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%AA), (2) [「ね」 vs 「な」 in 「そうだね」 /「そうね」/ 「そうですね」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13474/%E3%81%AD-vs-%E3%81%AA-in-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0%E3%81%AD-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%AD-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%AD)</sub>

Comment: I'm guessing this is the correct answer because yotsuba says something good about janbo, and her father adds something else good about him (doing the work of 2)

Answer (score 7):

“しな” = 接続助詞 “し” + 終助詞 “な”

“Aするしな。” implies something happens because of A.
Your example implies “Because ジャンボ works instead of someone (father?), he doesn’t have to work.”

Comment: This is actually the correct answer in context, I believe.  In a previous panel, they are discussing that somebody else didn't show up to help with the work, so Yotsuba's father is actually saying "Oh well, I guess Jumbo will do two people's work (because of Yanda not showing up)"