# use 味の感想も聞けるしな and 作りがいがある in this sentence

Tags: parsing, particle-も

> ここでは毎日味の感想も聞けるしな。特にアリスは、どんなメシでも笑顔で食べるから作りがいがある。
>
> mc that does all the cooking, talks about cooking while cooking
>
> Maybe it's because everyday i get feedback about my cooking from all of you. particularly Alice,  no matter what it is, because she eat it with a smile, I ... 作りがいがある。

味の感想も聞けるしな = 味の感想+[「詠嘆のモ」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32886/odd-use-of-%E3%82%82-has-me-stumped)+聞ける+し(cause)+な(かな。。?) ?

作りがいがある = i'm not sure

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I think there the も is the standard 'also'. This is because that clause ends with 聞けるしな, which is 聞ける + し + な,  where the ~し describe a list of reasons for something and the な is just a masculine sentence ending particle. Here's a related question: [しな at the end of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19287/%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)

作りがいがある =  作り+甲斐{かい}がある. The second part just means `something worth doing`. So here, it means making the food is something worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

作りがいがある
It is written in hiragana, so it may be difficult to understand
But in kanji it is like this:
作り甲斐がある。
甲斐 can be used as a suffix to mean "worth of"
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/甲斐/#je-9641](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%94%B2%E6%96%90/#je-9641)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/35252/meaning/m1u/甲斐/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/35252/meaning/m1u/%E7%94%B2%E6%96%90/)
So 作り甲斐がある means "it is worth making", "I have pleasure making".

味の感想も聞けるし
"And I can also listen to opinions about the taste"
The し at the end of the sentence simply means "and".